# SVN Update Unable to parse URL due to weird character

Tags: svn

I am getting the following message when I perform an svn update at the command line:

```
svn: Unable to parse URL '/svn/hvcp/!svn/bc/3678/trunk/media/mechanicârail_4.pdf'
```

This is what happened:

1. Accidentally saved a file that had a weird character (â) in its name
2. Performed a rename of the file within SVN on my desktop using TortoiseSVN and that seemed to succeed
3. Then tried to do an svn update from our dev server and keeps receiving the above message. When I blow away the file on my desktop and do an svn update on my desktop using TortoiseSVN it works fine with no message.

It looks like in the path it says /bc/3678/trunk which the 3678 is the revision number when that file was renamed.

SVN on CentOS release 6.3
Software version    4.0.4-3784.127
Subversion version  1.8.5-3784.127

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SVN use UTF8 encode. I think the filename is ok.

Maybe the client svn version is too lower to handle the filename correctly?

I meet the similar question when I use svn client with version 1.6 and svn server with version 1.8.

After I upgrade the svn client , it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when:

- You are using SVN 1.6 client or earlier
- You are accessing a server repository via http or https
- The repository is served by Apache 2.2.27 or 2.4.8
- You are directly accessing a repository file with characters that would need percent-encoded (anything other than ASCII alphanumerics and some punctuation)

The root cause is [Apache bug 56480](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56480). The SVN client performs a PROPFIND on the resource, and is returned an XML response with invalid URL encoding. SVN clients 1.7 and higher can cope with that, but not SVN clients 1.6 and earlier.

To resolve the problem, either upgrade the server to at least Apache 2.2.28 or 2.4.9 (which fixes the bug), or upgrade the client to at least SVN 1.7 (which works around the bug)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem with just spaces in the path when using SVN 1.3 client with an SVN 1.8 server.

Upgrading the client fixed the problem.